# Electron orbiting proton generating the electric current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

> There is an atom composed of an electron and a proton. The electron moves around the proton with a circular orbit of radius $r$. The proton and electron each has a charge of $+e$, $-e$. Calculate the current that the electron generates.

How can I solve this question? I tried to use centripetal force and the definition of current. I got $e^2\sqrt{k/m_e r}$ as an answer. Is it necessary to use unintroduced parameter $m_e$ to solve this question? Please tell me the detailed solution.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current is by definition a charge passing through a cross-section per unit time. Thus, you essentially need to calculate how many times the electron passes through a half-plane perpendicular to its orbit and multiply by the charge of the electron.

The mass and the charge of the electron are well-known constants, which can be easily found on the cover of the textbook or in the internet. This is why they are not specified.